# Using Len(Dir) to check for picture file and insert into file

Tags: excel, vba, image

I am trying to insert pictures into a column F. Links for picture files are listed in column C.

I researched on-line, and found a way.

If the file is there it works, if cell in column C is left blank it leaves the corresponding cell in column F blank, but if the link contains a file name does not exist it stops.

If the filename is corrupt = stated but not existing, I want to leave the cell blank and move on to the next cell.

```vb
Sub Insertpicture()

    Dim myPict As Picture
    Dim curWks As Worksheet
    Dim myRng As Range
    Dim myCell As Range

    Set curWks = Sheets(1)
    curWks.Pictures.Delete

    With curWks
        Set myRng = .Range("c2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "c").End(xlUp))
    End With

    For Each myCell In myRng.Cells
        If Trim(myCell.Value) = "" Then
            ‘do nothing, move on
        ElseIf Len(Dir(myCell.Value)) = 0 Then
            ’here I want to leave the cell empty and just move on to check next cell
    
       Else
           With myCell.Offset(0, 3)
               Set myPict = myCell.Parent.Pictures.Insert(myCell.Value)
               myPict.Top = .Top
               myPict.Width = .Width
               myPict.Height = .Height
               myPict.Left = .Left
               myPict.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
           End With
       End If
    
    Next myCell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the cell is empty, `Dir(myCell.Value)` will be the same thing as `Dir(vbNullString)`, which will return the next result from your last `Dir` command. Since `Dir` holds state this way, it isn't the ideal way to determine if a file (or lack of a file) exists.  I'd use the `Scripting.FileSystemObject` instead:

```
'Add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Sub Insertpicture()

    Dim myPict As Picture
    Dim curWks As Worksheet
    Dim myRng As Range
    Dim myCell As Range

    Set curWks = Sheets(1)
    With curWks
        .Pictures.Delete
        Set myRng = .Range("c2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "c").End(xlUp))
    End With

    With New Scripting.FileSystemObject
        For Each myCell In myRng.Cells
            If IsError(myCell.Value) Then
                'do nothing, move on
            ElseIf Not .FileExists(myCell.Value) Then
                'leave the cell empty
                myCell.Value = vbNullString
            Else
                With myCell.Offset(0, 3)
                    'You need to test to see if it's an image file here.
                    Set myPict = myCell.Parent.Pictures.Insert(myCell.Value)
                    myPict.Top = .Top
                    myPict.Width = .Width
                    myPict.Height = .Height
                    myPict.Left = .Left
                    myPict.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
                End With
            End If
        Next myCell
    End With
End Sub
```

Note that you also need to test for errors in the cells before you use the values and you should also either add error handling or test to see if the file you found was a valid image file.

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot for your input. This works just perfect. (I left the error handler out in the example) Instead of having a cell containing the picturepath, i would like"the path, cell value and filetype" to be written into the vba. But is having trouble with the coding. After setting strpath and strfile I state picpath to be "picpath = strpath & myCell.Value & strfile", with then "Set myPict = myCell.Parent.Pictures.Insert(picpath)" but this dosen't work. Could I impose on you again for this one?

Comment: Can see that this might need different vba all together.?

Comment: @roseq - Use the `FilesystemObject`'s [BuildPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0z2z1zt(v=vs.84).aspx) method instead of concatenating.